# How can I find the bug exactly when I use VScode to write a LaTex project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqFDs.png)
like the picture,it just tell me the code has bug,but does not show me where the bug is and how the bug come about.

I want to make some changes on the vscode so that it can show me the bug exactly but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: where in the picture is the 'bug'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.